# Looping through an array of promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I have some code that loops through an array of promises, and outputs the value.

```js
function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(seconds);
    }, seconds * 1000);
  });
}

const promises = [
  wait(1),
  wait(3),
  wait(2),
  wait(4),
  wait(5),
];

for (var promise of promises) {
  promise.then(seconds => console.log(`waited ${seconds} seconds`));
}
```

The issue with this is that the promise results don't get logged in the order of the array. My expected result is this:

```
Waited 1 seconds
Waited 3 seconds
Waited 2 seconds
Waited 4 seconds
Waited 5 seconds
```

And the result was this:

```
Waited 1 seconds
Waited 2 seconds
Waited 3 seconds
Waited 4 seconds
Waited 5 seconds
```

So I would like to have something like this

```js
function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(seconds);
    }, seconds * 1000);
  });
}

const promises = [
  wait(1),
  wait(3),
  wait(2),
  wait(4),
  wait(5),
];

for (var promise of promises) {
  // When the promise is resolved, log `Waited ${seconds} seconds`
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: You should do Promise.all to get them in order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the timers to start all at once, you shouldn't make all those `wait` calls at once. Instead only make the next call when the previous one's resulting promise has resolved:

```js
function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(seconds);
    }, seconds * 1000);
  });
}

const tasks = [
  () => wait(1),
  () => wait(3),
  () => wait(2),
  () => wait(4),
  () => wait(5),
];

(async function () {
  for (const task of tasks) {
    const seconds = await task();
    console.log(`waited ${seconds} seconds more`);
  }
})();
```

If you *do* want all promises to start at the same time, and want to wait for *all* of them to resolve before starting to output the results, then use `Promise.all`:

```js
function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(seconds);
    }, seconds * 1000);
  });
}

const promises = [
  wait(1),
  wait(3),
  wait(2),
  wait(4),
  wait(5),
];

Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
  console.log("all results are in:");
  for (const seconds of values) {
    console.log(`waited ${seconds} seconds (from the start)`);
  }
});
```

If you *do* want all promises to start at the same time, and want to wait for them to resolve only after the previous one resolved, then use `await`:

```js
function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(seconds);
    }, seconds * 1000);
  });
}

const promises = [
  wait(1),
  wait(3),
  wait(2),
  wait(4),
  wait(5),
];

(async function () {
  for (const promise of promises) {
    const seconds = await promise;
    console.log(`waited ${seconds} seconds (from the start)`);
  }
})();
```

Comment: @user18807217 the same pattern applies even if you make all your `wait` calls in the array. Just replace `const seconds = await task();` with `const seconds = await task;`

Comment: The timers start all at once sadly, and it should be when the 3 second timer is resolved, the 2 second timer has already been resolved, therefore, the 2 seconds complete message happens right after the 3 seconds complete message

Comment: It will be if you use your original array and make the change I indicated.  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w381o7td/)

Comment: Added some more alternatives.

Comment: @trincot best answer here

Answer (score 1):

Daniel A. White is right - use Promise.all() - something like this:

```js
function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(seconds);
    }, seconds * 1000);
  });
}

const promises = [wait(1), wait(3), wait(2), wait(4), wait(5)];

Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
  for (var seconds of results) {
    console.log(`waited ${seconds} seconds`);
  }
});
```

Comment: keep in mind this waits for all the promises to resolve before the `.then`

Comment: The issue with `promise.All` is that it wait's for *all* the promises to be resolved not logging to the console in the order of the array one by one.